# How to declare dynamic transition timing using Vue3 CSS v-bind?

Tags: vuejs3

In single-file-components, Vue3 has a nice ability to pass dynamic variables directly into CSS rules, [see docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css):

**This works...**

```
<script setup>
const theme = {
  color: 'red'
}
</script>
<style scoped>
p {
  color: v-bind('theme.color');
}
</style>
```

**... but, how to use it here?:**

Using `v-bind`, how can I pass a dynamic number in place of `0.5s`?

`transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(1, 0.3, 0.8, 1);`

For the `transition` to work, it needs "s" (or "ms") appended.

Is this a limitation of v-bind, and I have to form a string "0.5s" elsewhere, and pass the string entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a limitation of v-bind, and I have to form a string "0.5s" elsewhere, and pass it entirely?

Yes, but it is not too difficult. You can use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) with `v-bind` to create a string while keeping the data variable a number.

```js
import { computed, reactive } from "vue";
const theme = reactive({
  color: "red",
  transition: 0.5,
});

const opacityTransition = computed(() => theme.transition + "s");
```

```css
transition: opacity v-bind("opacityTransition") cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-monad-8jkgqy?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Does `v-bind()` need inner quotes?